# Firefox shows 'Your Connection is not secure' while connecting to google.com

Tags: firefox, malware, trojan

I reinstalled firefox and Kaspersky 17,and now I am geeting this message when trying to connect to google.com :

[image]

Sign of hidden malware?

My pc was infected and I reinstalled win 10 x64

Comment: You would have to check the advanced options and verify the certificate. What kind of internet connection are you using?

Comment: Does this error happen when using another web browser, such as Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is typically caused by your anti-virus trying to protect you
against Man-In-The-Middle attacks.

In order to be able to scan payloads in HTTP transactions, the anti-virus
generates its own root CA certificate and feeds spoofed certificates on the fly to your browser.
It installs the certificate into the OS certificate store, because
this is where most software looks to validate the Certificate Authority that
issued the certificate.

Unfortunately, FireFox is the only mainstream web browser that refuses to
trust the OS's cert store, precisely because it is so easy to install a fake
CA into it.
Instead, FireFox is distributed with a [complete list](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) of all CAs
that Mozilla trusts.

Kaspersky is well known for this problem. If it is indeed your anti-virus,
go to Settings > Web Anti-Virus > Advanced Settings > Configure trusted web sites > add as active:

```
http://www.google.co.uk/*        (substitute your country code)
https://www.google.co.uk/*
```

You might need to Uncheck and Check again the "Check URLs" to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this error (just a time I tried to use Firefox browser), and I consulted their website and here's what they had to say:

> When Firefox connects to a secure website (the URL begins with
>   "https://"), it must verify that the certificate presented by the
>   website is valid and that the encryption is strong enough to
>   adequately protect your privacy. If the certificate cannot be
>   validated or if the encryption is not strong enough, Firefox will stop
>   the connection to the website and instead show an error page:

Honestly I am not convinced about their explanation, that funny thing it never allow you to browse Google websites, and I doubt if this is certificate issues (some conspiracy maybe - a similar thing that Google uses when you are browsing under a VPN it never stops sending those captcha verification dialogs). So what goes around comes around.

(Jokes aside)

They claim its a bug caused by an antivirus software such as Avast (Even though I don't use Avast or similar AV).

Resolution

1. They claim one of the ways to resolve this is to disable HTTPS scanning.
2. Bypassing the warning

> - On sites with a weak encryption you will then be shown an option to load the site using outdated security.
> - On sites which certificate cannot be validated, you might be given the option to add an exception.

3.Fixing corrupted certificate store

You may also see certificate error messages when the file in your profile folder that stores your certificates (cert8.db) has become corrupted. Try to delete this file while Firefox is closed to regenerate it.

References

1. [Insecure Connection - "Your connection is not secure"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1104863)
2. [What does "Your connection is not secure" mean?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-does-your-connection-is-not-secure-mean)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates it is trying to connect without using SSL.  There could be many causes, such an AV program or something...  It doesn't matter why, really.

There is one solution that should work for you:

Install the [HTTPS-EVERYWHERE add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/https-everywhere/) and it will insist on using the secure method of connecting.

Problem solved.